# Do photons have a minimum energy in relation to the expansion of the universe?

Tags: cosmology, photons, temperature, low-temperature-physics

As the universe expands, background photons lose energy. Can that keep happening? After all, you can never reach zero temperature. So what happens to photons in the limit?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe

Answer (score 0):

As the energy of a photon decreases its wavelength becomes larger and larger. Therefore, if we start with an X-ray photon, we will eventually get a blue, green, and then red photon, before it becomes an infrared an then a terahertz photon, a radio wave and so on and so on.

So at zero energy the photons wavelength diverges and becomes infinite. As the photon must stay with the universe, this limit is only theoretically possible.

Comment: Could you edit your answer detailing what you mean by "As the photon must stay with the universe, this limit is only theoretically possible."?

Comment: The size of the universe is the limit for the photon's maximum wavelength.

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei but why would it have to be the case?

Comment: In the case of a flat universe, the universe is infinite.

Comment: In the case of "infintely" long wavelength the temperate would be absolute 0. Not sure this is possible.